# How can I trigger a select from a button with Angular Material?

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I have an `<md-select>` that displays a list of years. Great. When the screen reaches a certain width, i change the select to a `<md-button>`

I would like to listen to the button click and trigger the select to "open" for lack of better words. Or, is there a different method I should use?

Here is what I have - big surprise It's probably not what I should be doing. I understand this is a mobile framework - reasons beyond my control I am using it for my entire site. Thank you for any suggestions!

```
<!-- Mobile year begin -->
<md-input-container hide show-xs>
    <md-button aria-label="Select a year" class="md-icon-button" ng-click="">
        <i class="material-icons">date_range</i>
    </md-button>
</md-input-container>
<!-- Mobile year end -->

<!-- Desktop year begin -->
<md-input-container hide show-gt-xs>
    <label>Year</label>
    <md-select ng-model="myModel" class="md-no-underline md-body-1">
        <md-option ng-repeat="option in $ctrl.myYears" ng-value="option.year">
            {{ option.year }}
        </md-option>
    </md-select>
</md-input-container>
<!-- Desktop year end -->
```

This is my `component.js` file:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('year')
    .component('year', {
        templateUrl: 'path/to/template/my-template.template.html',
        controller: function myController() {
            /**
             * Year data.
             *
             * @type {*[]}
             */
            this.years = [
            {
                year: 2017
            },
            {
                year: 2016
            },
            {
                year: 2015
            },
            {
                year: 2014
            },
            {
                year: 2013
            }
        ];
    }
});
```

Comment: Obviously a button and a select input have different intended purposes. Is there some reason (other than aesthetics) that you're doing this?

Comment: The bigger issue is since we're using a mobile framework for a desktop app. So, by default I have a select input showing. As the window gets smaller, I run out of real estate and change to an icon. I will try your suggestion - thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd probably use a [menu](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/menu), and set the select model to match. Any change in the menu should update the select, and vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <md-menu>
    <button ng-click="$mdOpenMenu($event)">
      <md-icon>history</md-icon>
    </button>
    <md-menu-content width="4">
      <md-menu-item ng-repeat="option in $ctrl.myYears" >
        <md-button ng-click="vm.option = option">
          {{option.year }}
        </md-button>
      </md-menu-item>
    </md-menu-content>
  </md-menu>
```

So you can use a md-menu you  then use md-icon to give it an image.
The `<button ng-click="$mdOpenMenu($event)">` will open the the menu.
Use the md-menu-content with the md-menu-item with a ng-repeat to replicate a md-select. `<md-button ng-click="vm.option = option">` will set the default option to the one just clicked